# Yum fails with [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (111, 'Connection refused')> but TCP traceroute works

Tags: linux, routing, yum, networking

When I try to connect to yum repos using either yum info or yum install I get the error: `[Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (111, 'Connection refused')>` I first thought our Firewall may be to blame, but `traceroute -T -p 80 dl.fedoraproject.org` completes successfully, however `wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/repodata/repomd.xml` fails with connection refused.  I am a bit confused here.  What could account for this behavior?  This is a RHEL 5 box which I didn't setup and rarely access.  DNS is resolving fine, no static routes in the routing table, no proxy on the server that I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`traceroute -T` doesn't do what you seem to think it does.  It uses a TCP SYN packet to probe for the existence of a device.  Success in this means that it got some sort of response.  It is likely it did get a response:  connection refused.

Here's the Fine Manual:

```
   This  method  uses well-known "half-open technique", which prevents applications on
   the destination host from seeing our probes at all.  Normally, a tcp syn  is  sent.
   For  non-listened ports we receive tcp reset, and all is done. For active listening
   ports we receive tcp syn+ack, but answer by tcp  reset  (instead  of  expected  tcp
   ack),  this way the remote tcp session is dropped even without the application ever
   taking notice.
```

Comment: I assumed that a failure of that traceroute command would be a RST or no response, where a SYN ACK would signal a success.  No?

Comment: edited answer with detail from man page that answers your question.